# Getting errors when trying to apply SQL files with PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, automation

When I manually apply a SQL file, like a re-indexing job, everything runs perfectly.  I want to automate applying SQL files in powershell, but I'm getting all kinds of incorrect syntax errors when using `Get-Content`.  Is there a better way to get a SQL files contents, then apply those contents on a remote server that doesn't re-format the code to the point where I get incorrect syntax errors.

Generic error I get (any syntax might throw an error - ps seems to be mis-applying the syntax when getting the content of the file):

> Incorrect syntax near [anything]

Note: all `GO`s have been removed, so this isn't related to those; it may throw an error due to a begin, a goto, etc.  The reason is that it's not retaining how the SQL file is built.

**Update**

The SQL files can be anything from adding permissions to creating an index to building a table to creating a stored procedure.  I have about 100 SQL files.  If I manually execute them, they all work, so this isn't related to bad SQL syntax, but related to how Powershell is reading the SQL syntax and running it as a command.

**Answer**

The below appears to work:

```
Get-Content $file -Raw
```

Comment: can you show the `SQL` code

Comment: It can be anything from adding permissions to creating an index to building a table to creating a stored procedure.  I have about 100 SQL files.  If I manually execute them, they all work, so this isn't related to bad SQL syntax, but related to how Powershell is reading the SQL syntax and running it as a command.

Comment: Please saw ur powershell code??

Comment: But the error message belongs to SQL

Comment: When you use `Get-Content`  you should possibly pipe into `Out-Sting`.... `Get-Content $file | Out-String`. Does that change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I'm getting all kinds of incorrect syntax errors when using `Get-Content`

`Get-Content` will return an *array* of strings. What you need to be using is a single string. If you have at least PowerShell 3.0 then the `-Raw` switch is what you want.

```
Get-Content $file -Raw
```

Earlier versions you can use

```
Get-Content $file | Out-String
```

For exceptionally large files you can use .Net StreamReader's but I don't think that will be required here.

Answer (score 1):

How are you "applying a SQL file"? If you're passing the contents of the file into `Invoke-SQLCmd`, you'll need to use `-Raw` like @Matt said.

However, you don't even really need to do that. `Invoke-SQLCmd` lets you pass a filename directly into it. Use the `-Inputfile` parameter.